# How to programatically get the SDK version in Google Appengine (Python)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sdk

The current version of the Google Appengine is 1.8.8.

It would be useful to be able to look this up at runtime, *both on the development server and in production*, to check that my application is running on the correct SDK (because it's not necessarily the most recent).

I've tried `os.environ` as per [the Python runtime docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/#Python_The_environment) as well as the [App Identity API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/appidentity/) but neither appear to expose "1.8.8" on the development server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of

```
os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE']
```

is a string like

```
Google App Engine/1.8.8
```

or on development it's something like

```
Development/2.0
```

So you can just parse out the version number yourself, for example:

```
soft = os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE']
ver = soft[soft.find('/')+1:]  # Either '1.8.8' or '2.0' depending on version.
```

Comment: That's true in production, but on the (latest) development server the value of `os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE']` is "Development/2.0".

Comment: Good point @wodow, thanks! I corrected my answer to handle both cases.

Comment: So does "2.0" in the development map to "1.8.8"? In that case, what maps to e.g. version 1.8.7?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that there isn't a way of doing this consistently across the Appengine production platform *and* the development server.

So, to get the SDK version:

- In production: use `os.environ`.
- On the dev server: read the `VERSION` file in the GAE SDK directory (it's YAML format in version 1.8.8).